# passing Lua script from C++ to Lua

Tags: lua

I want to pass a Lua script (code that Lua interpreter can process) from C++ and get the result back.

I looked online but could not find any example that would help me. I am able to call a Lua function from C++, but that requires you to create a file with Lua function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using [luaL_dostring](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#luaL_dostring), which loads and runs a given string.